# How and when to use PIXI.RenderTexture

Tags: pixi.js

I am building a tool which visualises bicycle wheels. It uses approximately 100 PIXI.Graphics to build the entire wheel, which is all placed in a PIXI.Container and then rendered. It seems like quite a lot to render every frame, so I was looking into the PIXI.RenderTexture class and thought it might make sense to use it in this case. So question 1, is this a good use case? and question 2, how can I use it because I am having trouble working it out.

```js
const options = {
    transparent: true,
    antialias: true,
    backgroundColor: 0xffffff,
    resolution: window.devicePixelRatio,
    view: canvasEle,
};

const app = new PIXI.Application(width, height, options);

const wrapper = new PIXI.Container(); // Wrapper is used for zooming and panning the wheel
app.stage.addChild(wrapper);

const wheel = new Wheel(wheelOpts); // Returns PIXI.Container full of PIXI.Graphics
wrapper.addChild(wheel);
```

And my attempt to use the renderTexture is as follows. But I can't seem to work it out

```js
const options = {
    transparent: true,
    antialias: true,
    backgroundColor: 0xffffff,
    resolution: window.devicePixelRatio,
    view: canvasEle,
};

const app = new PIXI.Application(width, height, options);

const wrapper = new PIXI.Container(); // Wrapper is used for zooming and panning the wheel
app.stage.addChild(wrapper);

const wheelRenderTexture = new PIXI.RenderTexture.create(width, height);
const wheelSprite = new PIXI.Sprite(wheelRenderTexture)
wrapper.addChild(wheelSprite)

const wheel = new Wheel(wheelOpts); // Returns PIXI.Container full of PIXI.Graphics

app.ticker.add(() =>
{
  app.renderer.render(wheel, wheelRenderTexture);
})
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

I worked out how to use it and made a small jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hp98ygz5/1/

```
const width = 600
const height = 600

var app = new PIXI.Application(width, height, {backgroundColor : 0xffffff});
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

const wheelRenderTexture = PIXI.RenderTexture.create(width, height);
const wheelRenderSprite = new PIXI.Sprite(wheelRenderTexture);
app.stage.addChild(wheelRenderSprite)

const wheelContainer = new PIXI.Container()
//app.stage.addChild(wheelContainer)
wheelContainer.addChild(drawCircle(100,100,50,0xfec3dc,2,0Xfe68a4))
wheelContainer.addChild(drawCircle(100,100,20,0xFFCC66,2,0X55ff77))

app.renderer.render(wheelContainer,wheelRenderTexture)
```

I am not sure what was wrong with the above example but it works now

Comment: Answers the how but not the when ):